# Is a Java collection guaranteed to be in a valid, usable state after a ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

I am writing a GUI application using the [Immediate Mode GUI pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_Mode_GUI), and the UI runs on a thread separate to the engine that powers the actual functionality of the application. The GUI thread ends up iterating over many lists of objects that are conceptually "owned" by the engine thread, and these lists change extremely infrequently. The GUI thread is vsync'ed, meaning it runs at about 60Hz, and the engine thread runs at about 200Hz.

Sometimes, actions in the UI will change the contents of the collections in the engine, and I have a message-passing system to post Runnables to the engine thread to do these mutations to ensure that these mutations don't collide with what's happening in the engine. That way, I can ensure that the engine always sees a consistent view of the data, which for my application is very important.

Because the engine is in charge of all data mutations, though, it sometimes happens that the engine changes the contents of a collection while the GUI is iterating through it, and because these collections are standard Java collections, this predictably and correctly throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`. I can think of a few high-level ways to deal with this:

1. locking, either by using a synchronized collection or read-write locks
2. double-buffer the data that the GUI thread reads, and have the GUI thread flip the double-buffer when it's done drawing a frame
3. ignore the CME and abort drawing the rest of the frame, which will draw partial information for the frame in which the "bad" mutation happens, and just continue on to the next frame

Locking comes with a significant performance penalty, and while it would be fine for the GUI to sometimes stall while waiting to acquire the lock from the engine thread, it is very important for the engine thread to run at a consistent speed, and even an R/W lock would cause stalls in the engine thread. Double-buffering comes with significant complexity, as there is a *lot* of data that is read by the GUI on each frame.

I give you all of this background because I know that option 3 is ugly, and that my question is in some sense "not the right question". The Javadoc for `ConcurrentModificationException` even says:

> Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast operations throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: ConcurrentModificationException should be used only to detect bugs.

But! I am not concerned with the correctness of the GUI for the single frame that would be marred by the CME. I am only concerned with what happens on the next frame. Which leads to my question: is it safe to continue using a Java collection (I'm most interested in the answer for `ArrayList` and `HashMap`) after a `ConcurrentModificationException` has been thrown from its iterator? It seems logical that it would be, but I can't find a piece of documentation that says that the object will still be in a usable state after the CME is thrown. Obviously the iterator is toast at that point, but I'd like to swallow the exception and continue using the collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For most collections, as long as you only have one writer, you are probably ok, but there are no guarantees. If you have multiple writers on a HashMap you can end up with a corrupt map which has an infinite loop in it's structure.

I suggest you use `ReentrantLock` which has a `tryLock()` method if you want to support only-obtaining-a-lock-if-it's-not-being-used approach to minimise blocking.

Another way to feed data from one thread to another is to `Queue` modification tasks which the engine can pick up when not otherwise busy. This allows all access through one thread only.

BTW: A lock/unlock takes around 1 micro-second which is unlikely to make much difference to you unless you do this a lot.

Comment: Having multiple writers will not cause `ConcurrentModificationException`. Although the name makes it sound like a multi-threading exception, it is not. Single-threaded code can cause the exception too. --- E.g. having multiple writers on a HashMap, which may corrupt the map, will not cause the exception unless you're iterating it too, and lots of maps are never iterated. --- I believe your answer is missing the point of `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: I am queueing the modifications, but the issue is that both threads are reading heavily from this shared data, so one of them is always going to lose. The `ReentrantLock` is an interesting idea, because the engine could just defer
 the modification task to the next loop if the GUI thread is currently using the collection.

Comment: @HaldeanBrown You need to queue the entire task, both the reading and writing should be performed by only one thread if you want to avoid locking, or you have to use locking, or your data must be read-only.

Comment: @Andreas I am trying to solve the OP design problem rather than explaining what ConcurrentModificationException means, though you are correct and have a point, I don't think it helps the OP.

Comment: I think the reentrant lock to "reject" mutations until they can go through without blocking is the way to go, if locking is that cheap. When I prototyped a solution with locks I saw the engine get much slower, but now I'm thinking I must have made a mistake when I did that. Thank you Peter!

Comment: @HaldeanBrown When you lock you need to ensure it is locked for very, short periods of time, esp if you are not the GUI thread. You could add monitoring on how long the lock was held for and report if it was held for more than say 100 microseconds.

Comment: @PeterLawrey maybe I'm missing something; for this whole thing to work I need to lock the collection in question for the duration of the iteration, right? Some of those iterators definitely live for at least 1ms on a normal loop.

Comment: @HaldeanBrown I would structure your dataset so that when you update it, you don't need to iterate very much or at all so that you hold the lock for a very short period of time. When you are displaying the data, you can hold up the updates while you access the data, but again, I would try to hold the lock for as short a period as possible.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting part of the quote:

> Therefore, it would be **wrong** to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: ConcurrentModificationException should be **used only to detect bugs**.

*Conclusion:* Your code is buggy and needs to be fixed, so it doesn't matter what state the collection is in.

You should *never* get that error in valid code. It's an exception that should never be caught and acted on.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question, but am I correct in inferring that your actual answer is that the collection is in an undefined state, and thus should be considered unusable?

Comment: @HaldeanBrown I'm saying that you should never code around a `ConcurrentModificationException`. The exception it a non-guaranteed fast-fail that simply tells you, the programmer, that you've written bad code and the code needs to be fixed. The only correct action when receiving that error is to **fix** the code, not to add hacky code to work around it. The fact that you're even contemplating doing so mean that you missed the highlighted part of the quote, and that's what this answer is trying to teach you.

Comment: I think what Andreas is saying is that we don't actually know if the collection is unstable or unusable, or not.  All we know for sure is that it's an error, and the code needs to be corrected.  I'm pretty sure it's implementation dependent.  If you look at the code for a collection today, the data might be fine, and then tomorrow Oracle decides to change their implementation and it completely messes you up.

Comment: @markspace Actually, [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) only says that the collection was modified directly, while it was being iterated. It in no way, shape, or form is about whether that modification was incorrectly done. It just says that the **`Iterator`** is no longer valid. Multi-threaded update of a collection that is not thread-safe will not cause that exception, it will just silently corrupt the collection. The exception is **not about thread-safety**, regardless of the exception name.

Comment: That's completely right, and this is a thing I should add to my question; it is true that what I'm talking about is not about thread-safety, because my issue would still crop up if I were using synchronized collections. I could do all of my reads and writes in a thread-safe way but still have the problem with iterators that I'm having now.

Answer (score 2):

> The GUI thread ends up iterating over many lists of objects that are conceptually "owned" by the engine thread

Since the engine *owns* the data I argue that it should not openly share that data with the GUI.

Consider having the engine *push* data to the GUI rather than the GUI *pulling* (or reading directly) from the engines data structures. That way the engine has *full and exclusive* control of its data, as it probably should.

The downside is that this may take a significant redesign.

But the benefits may be significant enough to warrant it:

- No more `ConcurrentModificationException`
- No need for locks
- No need to constantly scan data and redraw, only when an update says to.

The last point could be significant depending on how much data you are dealing with or how complex your redrawing is. Pushing updates to your GUI will give you much more flexibility to optimize if profiling reveals the need to do so. For example, you could make better use of caches on the GUI side and invalidate those caches through updates pushed from the engine.

Answer (score 1):

> Locking comes with a significant performance penalty

Does it really? Have you seen if putting in a rudimentary gate/guard/lock/semaphore kills performance? At 60Hz/200Hz it's unlikely to do so.

Comment: My first pass at using locking came with a ~10% performance penalty; the problem is that the engine is a complex piece of code that accesses all of these collections in a bunch of different places, so I end up doing a lot of locking and unlocking. I could probably do a cleverer thing with fewer, larger blocks to reduce the performance penalty, but I got sticker shock after seeing the 10%.

Comment: I just saw Peter's edit saying that (un)locking should be near-instantaneous, which makes me wonder if I did a dumb thing when I wrote my locking implementation..

Comment: Just for your edification, try creating a simple driver class with a main method that leverages a bunch of different locking paradigms/primitives (synchronized, the lock types etc). A 10% performance penalty smells like something isn't quite right on the implementation side. Did you run your code through a profiler? Is your use case write-heavy?